# isolating a match with regular expressions and PHP

Tags: php, regex

still struggling with regex :)
i have this code:

```
$link = '/\bhttp:\/\/.+\..+[\/\w]?\b/i';
$match = array();
if (preg_match($link, 'http://bit.ly/hghjK6 bla bla',&$match))
{
    echo 'match'.'</br>';
    print_r($match);
}
```

as i'm trying to extract only the URL from the string i cant isolate it and the value inserted into $match always contain the "bla bla" taht follows the URL in my string
what is the regex needed to only match the URL and nothing else that comes after?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$r = '`(\s|\A)(http|https|ftp|ftps)://(.*?)(\s|\n|[,.?!](\s|\n)|$)`ism'; // regex to match a URL

$i = preg_match_all($r, $str, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
if($i){
  foreach($m as $set){
    // each $set in $m is a group of match
    // complete URL is
    echo $set[2].'://'.$set[3];
  } 
}
```

this matches ALL the URL in a text.

Comment: sorry about that Yaniv. fixed.

Comment: don't be sorry!
 I'm the asshole :) i forgot to change the $str to my string  (the curly braces is just a typing error)
now work like a charm :)
thanks for that!

Comment: no worries, i really found bug in my own writing. i missed out an open brace, missed out a ` at the start of the regex string and so on. cheerios for working code!